# C++ heap corruption detected: after normal block (#197)

Tags: c++

I'm learning about pointer but when I run my code it becomes like that:

```
heap corruption detected: after normal block (#197)
```

I don't know why, I deleted pointer to free memory
here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printfib(int n) {
    int* fib = new int[n];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    cout << fib[0] << "\t" << fib[1] << "\t";
    for (int i = 2; i < n + 1;i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
        cout << fib[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete fib;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    do {
        cout << "pls enter number: " << endl;
        cin >> n;
        if (n <= 1) {
            cout << "pls the number have to bigger than 1!!!" << endl;
        }
    } while (n <= 1);
    printfib(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last iteration of the loop assigns to `fib[i]` with `i == n` at this point. But you allocated `n` elements. Arrays in C/C++ are indexed with a valid range from 0 to `n - 1` (inclusively)

Comment: Also, you must pair `new []` with `delete []`, and `new` with `delete`. Other combinations cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: When you are done with learning about pointers. Make sure that in the future you would almost never need new/delete again. In general you should move to using C++ containers like std::vector/std::map etc. `int* fib = new int[n];` is then to be replaced by `std::vector<int> fib(n)`.  And if you need to allocate memory then use `std::make_unique`.  Also with std::vector you could have used `at(i)` instead of `[i]` and it would have told you where you went wrong.

Comment: While we are at giving secondary advise: [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: it is much easier to spot out-of-bounds issues in loops when you stick to `for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)`.

Comment: your `i` can reach value `n` ( since there is condition ` i < n + 1` if for loop) which [overflows your buffer](https://godbolt.org/z/fvGhdxfPr). Fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/hEGK4YW4M

Comment: BTW with your algorithm you do not need an array to perform this calculation. You need just track last two values of the sequence.